# ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER,Asking for JDK 7 and NO ADMIN rights

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use Oracle SQL Developr.

When I try to open it, it asks for the `jdk path`. Whereas I have only a `JRE` installed.
I do not have admin privileges and I can not get it that.

I have tried modifying the `sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.CONF` file but it did not help.
Is there any alternative to do that.

I have searched for around **3 hours** on Google. Nothing hits up straight.
And if you are planning to call it duplicate. I have gone through the similar questions but dint worked out. And installed as per the answer [How to start Oracle SQL Developer 4 using 32 bit JDK on Win 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225769/how-to-start-oracle-sql-developer-4-using-32-bit-jdk-on-win-64). But there also ERROR pops up when I start.

Comment: Do you think to install the JDK?

Comment: I do not have Admin privileges its clearly mentioned.

Comment: You don't need a JDK for SQL Developer. A JRE is enough. Does SQL Developer ask your for the location of a JDK/JRE when it starts? If yes, just specify the directory where your JRE is installed.

Comment: If you want to install de JDK on Windows without admin rights, you can follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name::It don't allow for JRE. It asks for the path of JDK and if i select the JRE directory it does not proceed.Either i am using the wrong version.Please check the link [oracle sql developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: ask for admin rights?

Comment: @Randy ::Forget it Buddy.That is next to Impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from this link just for getting it straight to the point[TRIED AND TESTED SOLUTION-With 100 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe)

As I have tried it and it really works.Posting the solution here.

JDK is not available as a portable zip unfortunately.
However, you can:

- Create working JDK directory (`C:\JDK` in this case)
- Download latest version of JDK from oracle (for example `jdk-7u7-windows-i586.exe`)
- Download and install 7-zip (or download 7-zip portable version if you are not administrator)
- With 7-zip extract all the files from `jdk-[6-7]u?-windows-i586.exe` in directory `C:\JDK`
- In command shell (cmd.exe) do the following:

  --> change directory to directory `C:\JDK\.rsrc\JAVA_CAB10`

  --> execute  command: `extrac32 111`
- Unpack `C:\JDK\.rsrc\JAVA_CAB10\tools.zip` with 7-zip
- In command shell (cmd.exe) do the following:

  -->  change directory to `C:\JDK\.rsrc\JAVA_CAB10\tools\`

  -->  execute command:

  ```
  for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"
  ```

  (this will convert all pack files into jar)
- Copy whole directory and all subdir of `c:\JDK\.rsrc\JAVA_CAB10\tools` where you want your JDK to be and setup manually JAVA_HOME and PATH to point to your JDK dir and its BIN subdir.

Thats all. After this you'll be able at least to use javac.exe

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the SQL Developer that comes bundled with the Oracle database. IME, it's not worth struggling with that.

I'd recommend using the [standalone version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) instead - it comes with its own JDK, all you need to do is unzip the archive.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, there's no standalone version of the current SQL Developer 4 for 32bit Windows. But you can use the [3.2.2 release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-v322-2080107.html) instead.

Comment: which one is stand alone in these ones?
I have installed the Windows 32/64-bit - Installation Notes.And it does not have jdk.Moreover they have given a link just above that for downloading jdk7.I guess if it does have its own they would not give that link on first place.

Comment: Use the "Windows 64bit - zip file includes the JDK 7" (310M)

Comment: @user3560140 You should have mentioned in your question that you need the 32bit version. Anyway, I've updated my answer with a link to v3.2.2, which is available for Win 32bit, as well.

Comment: Can't start MSVCR71.dll is missing???Any idea? and then unable to load java.dll something